# "all/only too" vs "far/much too"

Tags: meaning, differences

There are a lot of collocations with "*too*" that show different extents of something:
a little too, a bit too, rather too, far too, much too, etc

But there are two collocations that, as I was told, stand alone: "*all too*" and "*only too*". Here are several definitions of "*all/only too*" from the dictionaries:

> [collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/all-too-only-too): You use "all too" or "only too" to emphasize that something happens to a greater extent or degree than is pleasant or desirable.
>
> [macmillandictionary.com](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/all-only-too): used for emphasizing that you wish that something did not happen so much or that something was not true
>
> [ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/all-too-only-too): used to emphasize that a particular situation exists when you wish it did not exist

Looking at these definitions, I begin thinking that "*all/only too*" is the same as "*far too*" or "*much too*". But I was told that it is not so and, for example, the next sentence should be left with "*far too*":

> **(1)** *She was wearing a coat that was **far too** big for her*. — initial variant
>
> **(2)** *She was wearing a coat that was **all too** big for her*. — if we replace "*far*" with "*all*"
>
> **(3)** *She was wearing a coat that was **only too** big for her*. — if we replace "*far*" with "*only*"

Could you explain to me:

- why, based on the definitions of "*all/only too*", I cannot make up (2) & (3) that would be supposed to mean the same as (1)
- what the difference is between "*all/only too*" and "*far/much too*"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Far/much too big" is intended to be understood literally - the coat is a much larger size than the wearer requires.

Expressions such as "it was only too true" are figures of speech. A fact has turned out to be true when people had been hoping that it wasn't. The truth of a fact can't usually be measured; it either is true or it isn't. People don't literally wish that it was *less* true, but that it wasn't true at all.

Comment: Kate Bunting, in your second paragraph, you wrote what "_It was only too true_" means. But I don't understand why we can't write the same about "_far/much too_". I mean:

<< "_It was far/much too true_" – a fact has turned out to be true when people had been hoping that it wasn't. The truth of a fact can't usually be measured; it either is true or it isn't. People don't literally wish that it was less true, but that it wasn't true at all. >>

Could you help me to deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: I can't give you any more explanation than "that's how it is in English", I'm afraid. _It was much too true_ is just something that no-one would say.

Comment: "Much too big" means big to a very excessive degree that makes something impossible.  "Far too big' means big to a degree such that the excess is obvious and unmistakable.  These can only apply to characteristics on a scale.  "All/Only too true" means "true" against even the minimal hope of its not being true.  Each "jokingly" implies there is a scale involved even though none is.  Despite the surface structure, what is excessive is not the truth, but your hope that it is not true.  You can say: "it was all too true that the coat was far too big," but you can't reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

The strings given as examples aren't constituents; you're looking at the wrong end of the idiom. *Far, much, only,* and *all* are just modifiers for the negative word *too*, which governs several constructions, all of which come **after** the *too*.

*Too X for Y* means 'so X that Y is not possible'. *Too big for her* referring to clothing means it was so big she could not wear it properly; ditto for *too small/young/old/stylish/informal for her (to wear/pack/take/...)*.
Like any negative, there are degrees, and that's what *a little, much, way,* and *far* are for -- they're quantifiers, stating degrees of excess.

*Only* and *all* are different, however; they comprise idioms with *too*.
*All too X* and *only too X* both mean 'suspiciously too much X', as in

- *He was all/only too happy to take my  money*.

Comment: John Lawler, in spite of several definitions of “_all/only too_” (which I gave from the dictionaries in the original post), I still didn’t understand what it means in terms of its difference from “_far/much too_”. In your post I saw the next explanation: “_All/only too X_” means “_suspiciously too much X_”. Well, I can at least understand it (unlike the explanations of the dictionaries).

I think I could come up with a context: << “_She was wearing a coat that was all/only too big for her. Perhaps she's hiding something underneath_.”, one policeman said to another. >> Is it right? Thanks!